# SuiteCommerce Advance Out of Box Contents

Tags: netsuite, suitecommerce

I am very new to netsuite, and have a lots of task to work on it. anyone please guide me on this.

1. Out Of box contents of Suite Commerce Advance?
   What could be the possible contents when I'll get netsuite account login? Will I get default setuu with domain and site setup?
2. What about shopping experience? will I get default shopping experience?
3. What about checkout, payment, shipping methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Out Of box contents of Suite Commerce Advance? What could be the possible contents when I'll get netsuite account login? Will I get default setuu with domain and site setup?
```

- Standard customizable Ecommerce Site. You have to set up the domain but netsuite has a default which is somthing like shopping.netsuite.com/c..

```
What about shopping experience? will I get default shopping experience?
```

- Yes. It is like you can shop already for you to test.

```
What about checkout, payment, shipping methods?
```

- You need to set this up. NetSuite provides documentation for this.

Comment: Thanks, will mark just waiting for some more answer.